# boundedness for the maximum modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Is boundedness (of the domain of a function $f(z)$) is required to ensure that the modulus of $f(z)$ is bounded, for the application of the Maximum Modulus Principle (MMP)? If so why not require that $|f(z)|$ be bounded instead?

For example, if $z = x + iy$, and the function's definition domain is: $0 < x < 1$ with $y$ constant but can be infinite, while $f(z)$ is bounded in this "domain", can the MMP be applied?

Also, since there are different statements given in the literature, an exact, definite statement of the Maximum modulus Principle and the Minimum Modulus Principle would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the maximum modulus principle only applies to bounded domains. The unbounded version is called [Phragmen-Lindelöf principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle).

Comment: It seems like the issue is the boundedness of the function rather than the boundedness of the domain which in some cases is sufficient to ensure function boundedness.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the maximum modulus "principle" is that, for a (non-empty) bounded open subset $U$ of $\mathbb C$, for $f$ holomorphic on $U$ and extending to a continuous function on the boundary of $U$, the maximum of $|f|$ (which does occur on the closure of $U$, because that closure is compact and $|f|$ is continuous on it) occurs on the boundary. If it also occurs in the interior, then $f$ is constant.

Analogues for not-bounded domains need further hypotheses on the growth of $f$, for example, on a vertical half-strip, it suffices to require that $|f(x+iy)|\ll e^{|y|^m}$ for some $m$. Then if $|f(z)|$ is bounded by $M$ on the edges of the half-strip, it is bounded by $M$ in the interior.

That growth condition is certainly met if we know $|f|$ is bounded in the interior. Then the conclusion is that the bound is actually $M$.

(Note, the bound $M$ must apply to *all* points of the boundary, not just endpoints of intervals and such...)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Garrett. So if we know that f is bounded,can the maximum modulus be applied or just the analogues such as Phragmen-Lindelof principles/ theorems?

Comment: The maximum modulus principle's conclusion is still correct under some/various hypotheses, but/and those hypotheses are those of the Phragmen-Lindelof theorem. Thus, literally, it is Ph.-L. that one is applying, although the conclusion may be the same. That is, the proof of the maximum modulus principle does not work properly with an unbounded region... something more is needed, and this "more" is provided by the argument of Ph.-L.